# Feh show custom text on image

Tags: feh

I'm trying to find an example for `feh` image viewer that you can use to show on screen your custom text.

I wrote my own application which is doing some action and one of them is to show on the image screen and upon the image some additional text is also displayed, which I get from a server response.

All of the documentation that I found does not have enough information.

```
--info [flag]command_line
          Execute command_line and display its output in the bottom left 
          corner of the image. Can be used to display e.g. image dimensions or 
          EXIF information. Supports FORMAT SPECIFIERS. If flag is set to “;”, 
          the output will not be displayed by default, but has to be enabled 
          by the toggle_info key.
```

Does anyone have a command to show text as input or can also be read from a specified file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
--info "command"
```

which shows the output of the command in the bottom left corner of the picture. From `man feh`

```
--info [flag]commandline
        Execute commandline and display its output in the bottom left corner of
        the image.  Can be used to display e.g. image dimensions or EXIF informa‐
        tion.  Supports FORMAT SPECIFIERS.  If flag is set to ";", the output will
        not be displayed by default, but has to be enabled by the toggle_info key.
```

You can also use

```
--caption-path captions/
```

where you have text files with associated names for the picture files and the text in those files will be shown sidewise centered near the bottom of the picture.

```
-K, --caption-path path
        Path to directory containing image captions.  This turns on caption view‐
        ing, and if captions are found in path, which is relative to the directory
        of each image, they are overlayed on the displayed image.  E.g. with cap‐
        tion path "captions/", and viewing image "images/foo.jpg", the caption
        will be looked for in "images/captions/foo.jpg.txt".
```

It is also possible to control the size of the text, for example with

```
--font "yudit/24" 

-e, --font font
        Set global font.  Should be a truetype font, resident in the current
        directory or the font directory, and should be defined in the form font‐
        name/points, like "myfont/12".
```

---

I don't know if/how to move the output from the default locations except by output of spaces and empty lines to push the actual text to the right or upwards.

---

Demo commands,

```
$ find
./captions
./captions/sudodus-background.png.txt
./sudodus-background.png

S feh --caption-path  captions/ --font "yudit/24" \
--info "echo '           This is output from an echo command\n\n'" \
sudodus-background.png
```

Demo picture,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`feh --info "echo $mytext"` would do what you want – `echo` just prints the arguments it was given.

To read from a file, use `"cat $myfile"` instead.

Comment: Thanks
Is possible to align this text or is always bottom left?

Comment: please don't ask new questions in the comments; that's what opening posts are for! Thank you!